# Is this a valid Sigma equation to simplify?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Is that following a valid Sigma equation to simplify?

$$ T(n)= \sum ^n _{i=1} (2 + \sum ^n _{j=1} 4) $$

I know, how to solve if Sigma is like this:

$$ \sum ^2 _{n=1} 2n = 2(1) + 2(2) = 6$$

What are the $i$ and $j$ are doing there?
What happens with a constant attached to sigma like $ \sum ^n _{n=1} 2 $ ?

Comment: What is being summed in the $i$ summation after the first equals sign? As for $\sum_{i=1}^n 2$, that's a sum of $n$ terms each of which are $2$, so it is $2n$.

Comment: There's no equals, sorry corrected.

Comment: Do you really mean "n runs from 1 to n" at the bottom of the qeustion ?

Comment: Oh, so you have $\sum_{i=1}^n \left ( 2 + \sum_{j=1}^n 4 \right )$. Then the inner sum is $4n$ (from my previous comment), so the outer sum is then $n(2+4n)$. Note that the summands never depend on $i,j$ in this situation.

Comment: Thanks, I understood now. so I have $ 4n^2 + 2n$ as answer from simplification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When summing a constant such as

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^3 4 = 4+4+4=12
\end{equation}

one adds a $4$ for each value of the index.

Thus, 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n 4 = 4+4+4+\cdots+4=4n
\end{equation}

because one adds a $4$ for a total of $n$ times.